# Why I am Getting Same Error While Starting Application ? "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Error =>

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Business_Logic_Layer.Home.IHomeBLL' while attempting to activate 'BookReadingEventWebApplication.Controllers.HomeController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)**

**Startup.cs** =>

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

        }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/39YUb.png


**HomeController** =>

 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public readonly IHomeBLL _BLL;

        public HomeController( ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHomeBLL BLL)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _BLL = BLL;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var list = _BLL.GetAllEvents();
            return View(list);
        }


**HomeBLL** =>

public class HomeBLL : IHomeBLL
    {
        private Data_Access_Layer.HomeDAL _DAL;

        public HomeBLL(Data_Access_Layer.HomeDAL DAL)
        {
            _DAL = DAL;
        }

        public List<BookReadingEventModel> GetAllEvents()
        {
            return _DAL.GetAllEvents();
        }
    }

**IHomeBLL** =>

public interface IHomeBLL
    {
        public List<BookReadingEventModel> GetAllEvents();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to registers `IHomeBLL` service in `ConfigureServices`.

For example:

```
// or AddSingleton or AddTransient
services.AddScoped<IHomeBLL, HomeBLL>();
```

However, since `HomeBLL` depends on `(Data_Access_Layer.HomeDAL DAL)` and you'll need to follow this chain.

### Registering HomeDAL

*You're not showing what `HomeDAL` needs to be created the following is guesswork.*

Here are some options, and one may be applicable to you setup.

If `HomeDAL` needs to be created 'by hand':

```
// Create 
HomeDAL homeDAL = ...;
services.AddScoped<IHomeBLL>(provider => new HomeBLL(homeDAL));
```

Please note that it could be better if `HomeDAL` implemented an interface `IHomeDAL` and `HomeBLL` depened on `IHomeDAL`. Then if `HomeDAL` doesn't have any dependencies you could register both of them the following way:

```
// or AddSingleton or AddTransient
services.AddScoped<IHomeDAL, HomeDAL>();
services.AddScoped<IHomeBLL, HomeBLL>();
```

Comment: Thanks For Help.. It worked. I was stucked for so long... :)